How to formalise this (simple) proof on chromatic polynomials
Theorem 2.2
Let G be a graph with n vertices. Then P(G, q) is a monic polynomial of degree n with zero constant term and with integer coefficients that alternate in sign.
This is my current working,
Every vertex $v \in V(G)$ can be coloured using at most $q$ colours, less depending on how many neighbours that vertex has.
Then the expression for the number of colours at each $v$ is $(q-a)$ where a is some non-negative integer.
Then $P(G,q)=(q-a_1)(q-a_2)(q-a_3)...(q-a_n)$
We can see clearly that the signs should alternate as for the $q^{n-1}$ term we choose one $-a_i$ term to add so the coefficient must be negative, then for the $q^{n-2}$ coefficient we choose an $-a_i$ and an $-a_j$ term which makes a positive and so on.
It's also easy to see the constant term must be zero, as your starting vertex has $a=0$ as you have exactly $q$ colour choices to make, so when expanded out the constant term is 0.
I've had minimal experience with proof writing and don't quite get how to formalise this argument, all help appreciated!

This is not correct, the colors can't be chosen independently like that because the colors at a given vertex affect what colors its neighbors can have. The chromatic polynomial does not have integer roots in general. The proof I know uses the deletion-contraction recurrence: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deletion%E2%80%93contraction_formula
